# Measuring the reliability of a survey data

Tags: reliability, survey-sampling, cronbachs-alpha

I have a survey data and I applied KR20 on it. The KR20 score is 0.63 which means this survey result is not consistent and  reliable, at least not in a reliable range with the definition of a reliable score based on the majority of academic and industrial resources (i.e. above ~0.75). Similar results (i.e. low score) are observed by using Mcdonalds Omega and KR21. This is the distribution of the answers (binary responses):

[image]

summing all the Yes at the row level and then plotting the frequency of sums gives me this:
[image]

Which means majority of respondents only said Yes/No to a few questions which is concerning as an indicator that not all the questions measure the same objective.

Based on these figures, I conclude that the survey results are not very reliable. Is my line of thinking correct? Is there any other statistical tests that I need to apply to measure the reliability?

PS. I have been told that each responded had a few seconds to answer the questions and answers are Yes, No, I do not know.

KR20 code (result 0.63):

```
def kr20(df): 
    """
    Function to calculate Kuder-Richardson 20 score

    Args:
    * df: pandas DataFrame, containing dichotomous variables

    Returns:
    * kr20_score: float, KR20 score for the input DataFrame
    """ 
    # Ensuring no NA values
    df = df.dropna()
    if "customer_number" in df.columns:
        df= df.drop(columns=["customer_number"])
    # Calculate number of test items
    k = df.shape[1]
  
    # calculate variance of the test items counts
    total_var = df.sum(axis=1).var()

    # Calculate variance per test item
    column_var = df.var(axis=0)
  
    # Calculating KR20 score
    kr20_score = k / (k - 1) * (1 - column_var.sum() / total_var)

    return kr20_score
```

KR21 code (result 0.32):

```
def calculate_kr21(df):
    """
    Calculate Kuder-Richardson Formula 21 (KR-21) for a DataFrame with dichotomous survey responses.
    
    Parameters:
    - df: pandas DataFrame with dichotomous survey responses (1 for correct, 0 for incorrect).

    Returns:
    - kr21: Kuder-Richardson Formula 21 reliability coefficient.
    """

    # Ensure the DataFrame contains only 1s and 0s
    if set(df.values.flatten()) not in ({0, 1}, {1, 0}):
        raise ValueError("DataFrame should contain only dichotomous survey responses (1 or 0).")

    # Calculate the total number of items (questions) and the number of respondents
    total_items = df.shape[1]
    total_respondents = df.shape[0]

    # Calculate the proportion of correct responses for each item
    p_i = df.mean()

    # Calculate the overall proportion of correct responses
    p = df.mean().mean()

    # Calculate the variance of the item scores
    var_item_scores = (p_i * (1 - p_i)).sum()

    # Calculate KR-21
    kr21 = (total_items / (total_items - 1)) * (1 - var_item_scores / (total_items * p * (1 - p)))

    return kr21
```